# A Euro-iginal Sequence

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

Given a positive integer *n* output the *n*-th number of the euro-iginal sequence.

### Calculating the Sequence

<sub>This sequence is equal to OEIS [A242491](https://oeis.org/A242491).</sub>

A number is part of said sequence if the number can be made up by using as many different euro coins or notes, but **only one of each**. Note that you don't have to consider cents.

**Example:**

`6` would be in the sequence, as it can consist of a 1-euro coin and a 5-euro-note.

`4` would NOT be in the sequence, as it can't be formed with the given requirements.

To give everyone an overview, heres a list with euro values you have to consider:

> 1€, 2€, 5€, 10€, 20€, 50€, 100€, 200€, 500€

Note that this sequence only ranges from 0 (yes, 0 is included!) to 888.

---

Here are the first 15 elements of this sequence:

0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, ...

### Test Cases

**Input** -> **Output**

```
2 -> 1
6 -> 6
21 -> 25
33 -> 50
```

Comment: What is the largest possible input? Can we have some larger test cases?

Comment: May we index as `a(1)=1` like the [oeis table](https://oeis.org/A242491/list)?

Comment: Can we assune `N<=512`?

Comment: @xnor If it still returns `0` for `n=0` it's fine.

Comment: Can we output the 0-indexed results instead of 1-indexed? So `0->0; 1->1; 5->6; 20->25; 32->50; 511->888` instead of `1->0; 2->1; 6->6; 21->25; 33->50; 512->888`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sure, since that is basically what the OEIS sequence is.

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
b8d4ḅ5Ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//YjhkNOG4hTXhuIz/MHI1MTHCtcW8w4figqxH/w)

#### How it works

```
b8d4ḅ5Ḍ  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

b8       Convert n from integer to base 8.
  d4     Divmod each base-8 digit by 4, mapping the digit d to [d / 4, d % 4].
    ḅ5   Convert the quotient-remainder pairs from base 5 to integer, mapping
         [d / 4, d % 4] to (d / 4 * 5 + d % 4).
         The last two steps establish the following mapping for octal digits.
             0 -> [0, 0] -> 0
             1 -> [0, 1] -> 1
             2 -> [0, 2] -> 2
             3 -> [0, 3] -> 3
             4 -> [1, 0] -> 5
             5 -> [1, 1] -> 6
             6 -> [1, 2] -> 7
             7 -> [1, 3] -> 8
      Ḍ  Convert the resulting array of digits from decimal to integer.
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
lambda n:n+n/4+n/32*10+n/256*100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk87T98EiI2NtAwNgLSRqRmQYfA/Lb9IIU8hM0@hKDEvPVXD1NBI04qLs6AoM69EIU8nTSNP8z8A)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and 10*f(n/8)+n%8*5/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qTyExL0XB0EArTSNP30JTO0/VQstU3@R/Wn6RQp5CZp5CUWJeeqqGqaGRphUXZ0FRZl6JQp4OULHmfwA)

Comment: I keep looking at your math trying to figure out how you got to your solution. How _did_ you find that solution?

Answer (score 8):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>8 7</s> 5 bytes

```
Σ!Ṗİ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9odXNr///OoyHhuZbihpE5xLDigqz///8yMQ) **Edit:** -3 bytes thanks to Zgarb!

```
   İ€   build-in infinite sequence [1,2,5,10,20,50,100,...]
  Ṗ     power set [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[5],[1,5],[2,5],[1,2,5],...]
 !      index into the list with given input, e.g. 4 yields [1,2]
Σ       take the sum of that list
```

---

I heard that it is planned to change `İ€` to the finite sequence `[0.01,0.02,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,...,500]` in the future. Once that is implemented, the following code should work a byte count of 7:

```
Σ!Ṗ↓6İ€
```

where `↓6` drops the first six elements of the sequence.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9odXNr//8hbc6j4bmW4oaTNsSw4oKs////MjE)

Comment: Is it intended that the program adds 2 `0`s to the output?

Comment: `Σ!Ṗ↑9İ€` should save a byte.

Comment: @IanH. The first program produces the correct output. The second TIO link will only work after the implementation of `İ€` has been changed. That it is currently returning `2500` instead of `25` is merely a coincidence.

Comment: @Zgarb Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you can also remove `↑9`, since the challenge text doesn't mention what should happen for inputs beyond 512.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 29 bytes

**28 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

Uses 0 based indexing.

```perl
$_=sprintf"%o",$_;y/4-7/5-8/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCoMwEEDR/T@G2F2DmZnERErP4qoFQUxQN728qdsP79fPvsbW@vl91H3Zzm/3KN2zn1@/Ibg0RJeH1jyCYgQiI4nMhNxREEUMCUhERiQhGZlQj95GUUMDGtERTWhGJ8xjgt1Lu0o9l7IdzdX1Dw)

Comment: should be `sprintf"%o",$_-1`, because of sequence indexed from 1 for example `2 -> 1`, altough OEIS sequence starts with 1

Comment: This uses 0 indexing as allowed by the question (or at least, OPs comments under the question). I did have the `-1` until OP clarified!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
0Df9,4Ṇ$$#Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/AJc1Sx@ThzjYVFeWHO1f9///f2BgA)

Thanks a lot to [@Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer) for a lot of help in chat!

### Explanation

```
0Df9,4Ṇ$$#Ṫ  - Monadic link.

0        #   - Collect first N matches, starting from 0.
 D           - Digits.
  f9,4       - Filter-Keep the digits that are either 9 or 4. Yields [] when there are none.
      Ṇ      - Logical NOT. [] -> 1 (truthy), non-empty list -> 0 (falsy).
          Ṫ  - Pop and return the last element.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 47 bytes

```
(FromDigits/@0~Range~8~Drop~{5}~Tuples~3)[[#]]&
```

## Mathematica, 48 bytes

```
Sort[Tr/@Subsets@Join[x={1,2,5},10x,100x]][[#]]&
```

-6 bytes from Martin Ender

Comment: `Join[x={1,2,5},10x,100x]` and `Subsets@`.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>28</s> 26 bytes

0-indexed:

```java
n->n+n/4+n/32*10+n/256*100
```

Port of [*@xnor*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144450/52210) (which used to be deleted, hence the original 1-indexed answer below).

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hZBND4IwDIbv/ooemQRkQ7wg/gO5cDQeJh9mCIXAIDGG347lwyMxWbuue5r3TXPZS6uqU8yT1xgXsm3hKhV@dgAKddpkMk4hnJ5zA2Jjysh86gwUdFottYohBIQARrQuaOLhSOGKPXfoFt6JCmf0F77uHgXx61hfqQRKkjQi3Sh83u4g2aKXVc2spgLHB3XmUzbN9RMgerc6Le2q03ZNk7pAA23yx2Zzi71NSjg/bANwxR/A45ytaxjGLw)

---

Old 1-indexed answer (**28 bytes**):

```java
n->--n+n/4+n/32*10+n/256*100
```

Port of [*@Tfeld*'s Python 2 answer before he made his last edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/144451/5). Instead of using `~-` a bunch of times, it uses `--n` to decrease `n` by 1 right after entering the lambda function.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hVDLDoIwELz7FXsECUhBvCD@gVw4Gg@VhynClkAhMYZvr8vDIzHZR3c7k5lsyQduyybHMnvptOJdB1cu8LMDEKjytuBpDvE0zgtIjamiGdJmpKToFFcihRgQItBoX2wbLTwcKX1vz1zqXnCih6vDhdH0j4oYK3GQIoOaRI1EtQKftztwc1EsZDvriYiFIM4Rc6lZ1voLkLw7ldeO7JXTEFVVaKBDFs3Z3@JwE@WxH2wD4Pt/AAHzzPUSo/4C)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

0-indexed.

Port of [Mr. Xcoder's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144473/47066)

```
µN7nÃg_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0FY/S5PDzenx//8bGwEA)

**Explanation**

```
µ          # loop over increasing N until input matches are found
      _    # the logical negation of
     g     # the length of
 N         # N
  7nÃ      # with only 4s and 9s kept
```

Comment: Nice, seems like 05AB1E is the best tool for my algorithm :-). Dennis' arithmagic approach would get you 9 (maybe golfable) bytes: `8в4‰ε5β}J` (0-indexed)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: I had `8в4‰J5öJ` for 8 with Dennis' trick. Yours was better suited for 05AB1E indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>40</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

Inspired by [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144450/38592), but uses 1-indexing.

```python
lambda n:~-n*5/4+~-n/32*10+n/257*100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqk43T8tU30QbSOsbG2kZGmjn6RuZmgMZBv8LijLzShTSNAw1uWBMIwTTDEkUSYWxsSYXnGNqaKT5HwA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>78</s> <s>65</s> <s>62</s> <s>61</s> <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```python
lambda i,n=0:f(i+~-('4'in`n`or'9'in`n`),n+1)if i else~-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFTJ8/WwCpNI1O7TldD3UQ9My8hLyG/SN0SwtLUydM21MxMU8hUSM0pTq3TzftfUJSZV6KQpmGoyQVjGiGYZkiiSCqMjTW54BxTQyPN/wA)

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqk43T8tU30QbSOsbG2kZGmjn6RuZmgMZBv8LijLzShTSNAw1uWBMIwTTDEkUSYWxsSYXnGNqaKT5HwA)

Comment: Is there a reason @xnor deleted his answer, because it seems completely valid to me.. :S

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I've undeleted it now that the asker answered that shifting the indexing to `a(1)=1` is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 59 bytes

```matlab
@(n)unique((dec2bin(0:511)-48)*kron([1 2 5],10.^(0:2))')(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI0@zNC@zsDRVQyMlNdkoKTNPw8DK1NBQU9fEQlMruyg/TyPaUMFIwTRWx9BALw4oaaSpqa4J1PY/TcNIU0chTcMMTBoZgiljY83/AA)

#### Explanation

The code creates the full sequence and then indexes into it.

First, the binary expressions of the numbers `0`, `1`, ... `511` are generated as a 512×9 matrix:

> `dec2bin(0:511)-48`

(the `-48` part is needed because the result of `dec2bin` is characters, not numbers). This gives

```matlab
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
...
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Then the Kronecker product of `[1 2 5]` and `[1 10 100]` is computed

> `kron([1 2 5],10.^(0:2))`

and transposed

> `'`

which gives the nine possible euro values as a 9×1 vector:

```matlab
1
2
5
10
20
50
100
200
500
```

Matrix-multiplying the above matrix and vector

> `*`

gives a 512×1 vector containing all possible numbers in the sequence, with repetitions and unsorted:

```matlab
  0
500
 50
...
388
888
```

Deduplicating and sorting

> `unique(...)`

gives the full sequence:

```matlab
  0
  1
  2
...
887
888
```

Finally, the input is used to index into this sequence

> `(n)`

to produce the output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

0-indexed.

```
æ»“£¦®‘×“¢½d‘S+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wskO7HzXMObT40LJD6x41zDg8HcRbdGhvCpATrP3//39jIwA)

### Explanation

This is based off of [xnor's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144450), where the algorithm is **n + n/4 + n/32*10 + n/256*100**.

```
lambda n: sum(i * j for i, j in zip([n / i for i in [1, 4, 32, 256]], [1, 1, 10, 100]]))
```

Since the first **n** is unmodified, this is the same as:

```
lambda n: sum(i * j for i, j in zip([n / i for i in [4, 32, 256]], [1, 10, 100]])) + n
```

Since 4, 32, and 256 are all powers of two, they can be translated into bit shifts.

```
lambda n: sum(i * j for i, j in zip([n >> i for i in [2, 5, 8]], [1, 10, 100]])) + n
```

The golfiness doesn't translate well in Python, but turning the lists into Jelly strings of code page indices reduces Jelly's byte count.

```
lambda n: sum(i * j for i, j in zip([n >> i for i in map(jelly_codepage.index, '£¦®')], map(jelly_codepage.index, '¢½d'))) + n
```

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
“¡¿ɼcÞµ³Ṡf2ż’bȷ3ŒPS€Ṣ
ị¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9qZWxsef//4oCcwqHCv8m8Y8OewrXCs@G5oGYyxbzigJliyLczxZJQU@KCrOG5ogrhu4vCov///zMz)

Comment: +1 for having `€` in your code. :) But -1 because this is the first time ever a Jelly answer is longer than my Java answer. XD Shame on you (and gl & hf golfing it further). ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen This is going to wreak havoc on the [Elo ratings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8891/20260).

Comment: @KevinCrujissen A bit better now? :P

Comment: @icrieverytim You made a typo in my name, so I didn't get the summon. But yes, a lot better. :) +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```ruby
->x{("%o"%x).tr"4-7","5-8"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iWkNJNV9JtUJTr6RIyUTXXElHyVTXQqn2v4aBnp6hgYGmXm5iQXVNRY1CgUJ0hY5CWnRFbGztfwA)

#### Explanation

Output octal string, replace digits 4..7 with 5..8

Comment: I think you can remove the space after .tr for -1

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 20

```bash
dc -e8o?p|tr 4-7 5-8
```

Reads a zero-indexed index from STDIN.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kUJJaXJKcWJyqkJmnYKhgqmBkoGBsZK2Qks@loJCanJGvoAJXUaPwPyVZQTfVIt@@oKakSMFE11zBVNfif0p@Xup/AA).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

```
9LD3%n>s3/óTsm*æO{sè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0sfFWDXPrthY//DmkOJcrcPL/KuLD6/4/9/YCAA)

---

1-indexed, using the formula of `[(n%3)^2 + 1]*10^floor(n/3)` to generate the first 10 terms, then using powerset to calculate all possible combinations... Then I sort it and pull `a[b]`.

---

See it in action below:

```
Full program: 9LD3%n>s3/óTsm*æO{sè
current >> 9  ||  stack: []
current >> L  ||  stack: ['9']
current >> D  ||  stack: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
current >> 3  ||  stack: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
current >> %  ||  stack: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], '3']
current >> n  ||  stack: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]]
current >> >  ||  stack: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 4, 0]]
current >> s  ||  stack: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1]]
current >> 3  ||  stack: [[2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
current >> /  ||  stack: [[2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], '3']
current >> ó  ||  stack: [[2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1], [0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 1.0, 1.3333333333333333, 1.6666666666666667, 2.0, 2.3333333333333335, 2.6666666666666665, 3.0]]
current >> T  ||  stack: [[2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]]
current >> s  ||  stack: [[2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 10]
current >> m  ||  stack: [[2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1], 10, [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]]
current >> *  ||  stack: [[2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1], [1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100]]
current >> æ  ||  stack: [[2, 5, 1, 20, 50, 10, 200, 500, 100]]
current >> O  ||  stack: < OMITTED, THE RESULT OF POWERSET IS HUGE >
current >> {  ||  stack: [[0, 2, 5, 1, 20, 50, 10, 200, 500, 100, 7, 3, 22, 52, 12, 202, 502, 102, 6, 25, 55, 15, 205, 505, 105, 21, 51, 11, 201, 501, 101, 70, 30, 220, 520, 120, 60, 250, 550, 150, 210, 510, 110, 700, 300, 600, 8, 27, 57, 17, 207, 507, 107, 23, 53, 13, 203, 503, 103, 72, 32, 222, 522, 122, 62, 252, 552, 152, 212, 512, 112, 702, 302, 602, 26, 56, 16, 206, 506, 106, 75, 35, 225, 525, 125, 65, 255, 555, 155, 215, 515, 115, 705, 305, 605, 71, 31, 221, 521, 121, 61, 251, 551, 151, 211, 511, 111, 701, 301, 601, 80, 270, 570, 170, 230, 530, 130, 720, 320, 620, 260, 560, 160, 750, 350, 650, 710, 310, 610, 800, 28, 58, 18, 208, 508, 108, 77, 37, 227, 527, 127, 67, 257, 557, 157, 217, 517, 117, 707, 307, 607, 73, 33, 223, 523, 123, 63, 253, 553, 153, 213, 513, 113, 703, 303, 603, 82, 272, 572, 172, 232, 532, 132, 722, 322, 622, 262, 562, 162, 752, 352, 652, 712, 312, 612, 802, 76, 36, 226, 526, 126, 66, 256, 556, 156, 216, 516, 116, 706, 306, 606, 85, 275, 575, 175, 235, 535, 135, 725, 325, 625, 265, 565, 165, 755, 355, 655, 715, 315, 615, 805, 81, 271, 571, 171, 231, 531, 131, 721, 321, 621, 261, 561, 161, 751, 351, 651, 711, 311, 611, 801, 280, 580, 180, 770, 370, 670, 730, 330, 630, 820, 760, 360, 660, 850, 810, 78, 38, 228, 528, 128, 68, 258, 558, 158, 218, 518, 118, 708, 308, 608, 87, 277, 577, 177, 237, 537, 137, 727, 327, 627, 267, 567, 167, 757, 357, 657, 717, 317, 617, 807, 83, 273, 573, 173, 233, 533, 133, 723, 323, 623, 263, 563, 163, 753, 353, 653, 713, 313, 613, 803, 282, 582, 182, 772, 372, 672, 732, 332, 632, 822, 762, 362, 662, 852, 812, 86, 276, 576, 176, 236, 536, 136, 726, 326, 626, 266, 566, 166, 756, 356, 656, 716, 316, 616, 806, 285, 585, 185, 775, 375, 675, 735, 335, 635, 825, 765, 365, 665, 855, 815, 281, 581, 181, 771, 371, 671, 731, 331, 631, 821, 761, 361, 661, 851, 811, 780, 380, 680, 870, 830, 860, 88, 278, 578, 178, 238, 538, 138, 728, 328, 628, 268, 568, 168, 758, 358, 658, 718, 318, 618, 808, 287, 587, 187, 777, 377, 677, 737, 337, 637, 827, 767, 367, 667, 857, 817, 283, 583, 183, 773, 373, 673, 733, 333, 633, 823, 763, 363, 663, 853, 813, 782, 382, 682, 872, 832, 862, 286, 586, 186, 776, 376, 676, 736, 336, 636, 826, 766, 366, 666, 856, 816, 785, 385, 685, 875, 835, 865, 781, 381, 681, 871, 831, 861, 880, 288, 588, 188, 778, 378, 678, 738, 338, 638, 828, 768, 368, 668, 858, 818, 787, 387, 687, 877, 837, 867, 783, 383, 683, 873, 833, 863, 882, 786, 386, 686, 876, 836, 866, 885, 881, 788, 388, 688, 878, 838, 868, 887, 883, 886, 888]]
current >> s  ||  stack: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 88, 100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 110, 111, 112, 113, 115, 116, 117, 118, 120, 121, 122, 123, 125, 126, 127, 128, 130, 131, 132, 133, 135, 136, 137, 138, 150, 151, 152, 153, 155, 156, 157, 158, 160, 161, 162, 163, 165, 166, 167, 168, 170, 171, 172, 173, 175, 176, 177, 178, 180, 181, 182, 183, 185, 186, 187, 188, 200, 201, 202, 203, 205, 206, 207, 208, 210, 211, 212, 213, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223, 225, 226, 227, 228, 230, 231, 232, 233, 235, 236, 237, 238, 250, 251, 252, 253, 255, 256, 257, 258, 260, 261, 262, 263, 265, 266, 267, 268, 270, 271, 272, 273, 275, 276, 277, 278, 280, 281, 282, 283, 285, 286, 287, 288, 300, 301, 302, 303, 305, 306, 307, 308, 310, 311, 312, 313, 315, 316, 317, 318, 320, 321, 322, 323, 325, 326, 327, 328, 330, 331, 332, 333, 335, 336, 337, 338, 350, 351, 352, 353, 355, 356, 357, 358, 360, 361, 362, 363, 365, 366, 367, 368, 370, 371, 372, 373, 375, 376, 377, 378, 380, 381, 382, 383, 385, 386, 387, 388, 500, 501, 502, 503, 505, 506, 507, 508, 510, 511, 512, 513, 515, 516, 517, 518, 520, 521, 522, 523, 525, 526, 527, 528, 530, 531, 532, 533, 535, 536, 537, 538, 550, 551, 552, 553, 555, 556, 557, 558, 560, 561, 562, 563, 565, 566, 567, 568, 570, 571, 572, 573, 575, 576, 577, 578, 580, 581, 582, 583, 585, 586, 587, 588, 600, 601, 602, 603, 605, 606, 607, 608, 610, 611, 612, 613, 615, 616, 617, 618, 620, 621, 622, 623, 625, 626, 627, 628, 630, 631, 632, 633, 635, 636, 637, 638, 650, 651, 652, 653, 655, 656, 657, 658, 660, 661, 662, 663, 665, 666, 667, 668, 670, 671, 672, 673, 675, 676, 677, 678, 680, 681, 682, 683, 685, 686, 687, 688, 700, 701, 702, 703, 705, 706, 707, 708, 710, 711, 712, 713, 715, 716, 717, 718, 720, 721, 722, 723, 725, 726, 727, 728, 730, 731, 732, 733, 735, 736, 737, 738, 750, 751, 752, 753, 755, 756, 757, 758, 760, 761, 762, 763, 765, 766, 767, 768, 770, 771, 772, 773, 775, 776, 777, 778, 780, 781, 782, 783, 785, 786, 787, 788, 800, 801, 802, 803, 805, 806, 807, 808, 810, 811, 812, 813, 815, 816, 817, 818, 820, 821, 822, 823, 825, 826, 827, 828, 830, 831, 832, 833, 835, 836, 837, 838, 850, 851, 852, 853, 855, 856, 857, 858, 860, 861, 862, 863, 865, 866, 867, 868, 870, 871, 872, 873, 875, 876, 877, 878, 880, 881, 882, 883, 885, 886, 887, 888]]
current >> è  ||  stack: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 88, 100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 110, 111, 112, 113, 115, 116, 117, 118, 120, 121, 122, 123, 125, 126, 127, 128, 130, 131, 132, 133, 135, 136, 137, 138, 150, 151, 152, 153, 155, 156, 157, 158, 160, 161, 162, 163, 165, 166, 167, 168, 170, 171, 172, 173, 175, 176, 177, 178, 180, 181, 182, 183, 185, 186, 187, 188, 200, 201, 202, 203, 205, 206, 207, 208, 210, 211, 212, 213, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223, 225, 226, 227, 228, 230, 231, 232, 233, 235, 236, 237, 238, 250, 251, 252, 253, 255, 256, 257, 258, 260, 261, 262, 263, 265, 266, 267, 268, 270, 271, 272, 273, 275, 276, 277, 278, 280, 281, 282, 283, 285, 286, 287, 288, 300, 301, 302, 303, 305, 306, 307, 308, 310, 311, 312, 313, 315, 316, 317, 318, 320, 321, 322, 323, 325, 326, 327, 328, 330, 331, 332, 333, 335, 336, 337, 338, 350, 351, 352, 353, 355, 356, 357, 358, 360, 361, 362, 363, 365, 366, 367, 368, 370, 371, 372, 373, 375, 376, 377, 378, 380, 381, 382, 383, 385, 386, 387, 388, 500, 501, 502, 503, 505, 506, 507, 508, 510, 511, 512, 513, 515, 516, 517, 518, 520, 521, 522, 523, 525, 526, 527, 528, 530, 531, 532, 533, 535, 536, 537, 538, 550, 551, 552, 553, 555, 556, 557, 558, 560, 561, 562, 563, 565, 566, 567, 568, 570, 571, 572, 573, 575, 576, 577, 578, 580, 581, 582, 583, 585, 586, 587, 588, 600, 601, 602, 603, 605, 606, 607, 608, 610, 611, 612, 613, 615, 616, 617, 618, 620, 621, 622, 623, 625, 626, 627, 628, 630, 631, 632, 633, 635, 636, 637, 638, 650, 651, 652, 653, 655, 656, 657, 658, 660, 661, 662, 663, 665, 666, 667, 668, 670, 671, 672, 673, 675, 676, 677, 678, 680, 681, 682, 683, 685, 686, 687, 688, 700, 701, 702, 703, 705, 706, 707, 708, 710, 711, 712, 713, 715, 716, 717, 718, 720, 721, 722, 723, 725, 726, 727, 728, 730, 731, 732, 733, 735, 736, 737, 738, 750, 751, 752, 753, 755, 756, 757, 758, 760, 761, 762, 763, 765, 766, 767, 768, 770, 771, 772, 773, 775, 776, 777, 778, 780, 781, 782, 783, 785, 786, 787, 788, 800, 801, 802, 803, 805, 806, 807, 808, 810, 811, 812, 813, 815, 816, 817, 818, 820, 821, 822, 823, 825, 826, 827, 828, 830, 831, 832, 833, 835, 836, 837, 838, 850, 851, 852, 853, 855, 856, 857, 858, 860, 861, 862, 863, 865, 866, 867, 868, 870, 871, 872, 873, 875, 876, 877, 878, 880, 881, 882, 883, 885, 886, 887, 888], '32']
50
stack > [50]
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```
n=>--n+(n>>2)+(n>>5)*10+(n>>8)*100
```

Or 32 bytes using the correct 0-indexing:

```js
f=
n=>n+(n>>2)+(n>>5)*10+(n>>8)*100
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 max=511 value=0 oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)><pre id=o>0
```

Comment: Shouldn't `n=1` give `0`?

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

Uses [Dennis' witchcraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144474/59487).

```
jkiR5.DR4jQ8
```

**[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jkiR5.DR4jQ8&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A5%0A20%0A32&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth),  <s>16 15</s>  13 bytes

```
e.f!@,9 4jZTt
```

**[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.f%21%40%2C9+4jZTt&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A6%0A21%0A33&debug=0)**

Thanks to [Erik the Outgofer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40371070#40371070) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
53b6×þ“¢½d‘FŒPS€Ṣị@‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/UOMns8PTD@x41zDm06NDelEcNM9yOTgoIftS05uHORQ93dzsARf4fbgfy//8vSsxLT9Uw1DE01wQA)

I know this is longer than the existing answer but I think this approach is golfable from here :P

-2 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

Comment: `1,10,ȷ2` -> `“¢½d‘`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 42 bytes

```
.+
$*1;
+`(1+)\1{7}
$1;
1111
1$&
(1*);
$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRcvQmks7QcNQWzPGsNq8lksFyDcEAi5DFTUuDUMtTWsuFT3D//8NuUy5jAy4jI0A) Link includes test cases. 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
.+
$*1;
```

Convert from decimal to unary, with a `;` suffix.

```
+`(1+)\1{7}
$1;
```

Convert to octal, but still using unary representation of the digits with `;` after each unary value.

```
1111
1$&
```

Add 1 to the values 4-7.

```
(1*);
$.1
```

Convert each value plus its suffix to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

## [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)), 67 bytes

```c
main(n){scanf("%d",&n);printf("%d",n+(n>>2)+(n>>5)*10+(n>>8)*100);}
```

A direct port from [Neil's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144456/66000), but I thought this should be added for completeness.

---

Tested on GCC version 6.3.0. It will throw some warnings, but compile anyway.